# Multiple SQL Query Criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

Is there a way to apply the following criteria in an Access query?

Union query does not provide all three criteria

```
LName, FName 
Where (TourID=14XXX and Status=0) AND 
      (TourID=16XXX and Status=1) AND 
      (TourID=20XXX and Status=1)
```

Only return results where all three criteria are true

Comment: What about changing both upper case "AND" by "OR" ? (the "and" outside parenthesis, I mean, the two outer "AND")

Answer (score 0):

Use OR instead of AND

```
select LName, FName from tablename
Where (TourID=14XXX and Status=0) OR
      (TourID=16XXX and Status=1) OR
      (TourID=20XXX and Status=1)
```

Comment: OR either of the three conditions as opposed to returning only if all three are true.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want aggregation:

```
SELECT LName, FName 
FROM t
WHERE (TourID=14XXX and Status=0) OR 
      (TourID=16XXX and Status=1) OR 
      (TourID=20XXX and Status=1)
GROUP BY LName, FName 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3;
```

The `COUNT(*)` assumes that tours are not duplicated in the original table.

```
SELECT LName, FName 
FROM t
WHERE (TourID=14XXX and Status=0) OR 
      (TourID=16XXX and Status=1) OR 
      (TourID=20XXX and Status=1)
GROUP BY LName, FName 
HAVING SUM(IIF(TourID=14XXX AND Status=0, 1, 0)) > 0 AND
       SUM(IIF(TourID=16XXX and Status=1, 1, 0)) > 0 AND
       SUM(IIF(TourID=20XXX and Status=1, 1, 0)) > 0;
```

Comment: I tried modifying my SQL based on your suggestion but now luck
SELECT tblCustomers.LastName, tblCustomers.FirstName
FROM tblCustomers INNER JOIN tblTourBookings ON tblCustomers.CustomerID = tblTourBookings.CustomerID
WHERE (((tblTourBookings.TourID)="20xxxx") AND ((tblTourBookings.BookingStatusID)<>0)) OR (((tblTourBookings.TourID)="16xxxx") AND ((tblTourBookings.BookingStatusID)=1)) OR (((tblTourBookings.TourID)="14xxxx") AND ((tblTourBookings.BookingStatusID)=1))
GROUP BY tblCustomers.LastName, tblCustomers.FirstName
HAVING (((Count(*))=3));

Comment: And how does that fail?